# What is the easiest way to format a currency in HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to auto format a number that is being entered into an input box as currency.  For example, if I enter 1023, then I want it to be formatted as 10.23, so the user has the option to enter the decimal.  I would like this to happen while the user is in the input, so they do not have to leave the box for the change to occur.  I have looked over SO and I know it has to be there, but I must not be using the right query to find it.  Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: you're looking for a mask http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/ do try to google other plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used in [autonumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) but
there are lots of mask plugins, another I have used is
[this jquery currency plugin](http://dev7studios.com/demo/jquery-currency/)

```
$('#basic').currency();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery plugin (masking) : http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I use a js library in order to achive.

Take a look at it.

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/